# How can I concatenate field values together from other records in same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table as below in MySQL. All I want to do is group records by PARENT ID and concatenate ATTRIBUTE records for that PARENT ID into the TYPE='SIMPLE' record.

| UNIQUE ID | TYPE | Parent ID | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MYID1 | SIMPLE | MYID1 |  |
| MYID2 | VARIANT | MYID1 | WHITE |
| MYID3 | VARIANT | MYID1 | BLUE |

So the result would be;

| UNIQUE ID | TYPE | Parent ID | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MYID1 | SIMPLE | MYID1 | WHITE, BLUE |
| MYID2 | VARIANT | MYID1 | WHITE |
| MYID3 | VARIANT | MYID1 | BLUE |

How would I go about this?

Comment: Try using GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Perfect. Just had a look and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used GROUP_CONCAT very successfully